# She spilled the green beans

Tags: word-usage

She was holding a green beans bag and accidentally dropped it.

The beans were all over the floor.

My son saw it and told me,

> "She spilled the green beans."

I always saw this word use for water, milk and soup.

Could it be use for green bean?

Comment: Rather than "green beans bag", you want "bag of green beans", and at the end you want "for green bean**s**" rather than just "green bean" :-)

Comment: Also please note that "spill the beans" is an idiom - I thought question is related. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spill+the+beans

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use **spilled** for green beans (or any other kind of beans).  In fact, [*to spill the beans*](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/spill-the-beans.html) is a very common metaphor, meaning "to reveal a secret".

We usually use *spill* with liquids, but it can be used with anything that flows like liquid, such as beans, [rice](https://books.google.com/books?id=3mjqAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA15&dq=%22spilled%20the%20rice%22&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q=%22spilled%20the%20rice%22&f=false), [grain](https://books.google.com/books?id=e0pxsLSDrrwC&lpg=PA221&dq=%22spilled%20the%20grain%22&pg=PA221#v=onepage&q=%22spilled%20the%20grain%22&f=false), [sand](https://books.google.com/books?id=xy1_sJvqu18C&lpg=PT63&dq=%22spill%20the%20sand%22&pg=PT63#v=onepage&q=%22spill%20the%20sand%22&f=false), [salt](https://books.google.com/books?id=d7qjDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT392&dq=%22spill%20the%20salt%22&pg=PT392#v=onepage&q=%22spill%20the%20salt%22&f=false), etc.  You wouldn't use it with something more solid, like "steak" - "Spill the steak" doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think it can even work with bigger items, too, like [peaches](https://books.google.com/books?id=NwFP_8W_JRsC&pg=PT354&dq=%22spilled+the+peaches%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjsbeHicPWAhUCMyYKHYTgCUwQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22spilled%20the%20peaches%22&f=false).

Comment: Or if you had a container with a bunch of e.g., frozen steaks, "spilled the steaks" would be fine.

Comment: If you drop the bag and none come spilling out then it wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 6):

Spilled is used more for something *escaping a container*. Usually a liquid, occasionally multiples of a solid, and rarely a single solid item. For example, these all make some sense:

> Milk spilled on the table and floor.
>       Beans spilled out of the bag.
>       Frozen steaks spilled out on the road. (Imagine an overturned truck)
>       A steak spilled out of the of the overturned grocery bag.

Define 'spilled' gives:

> - cause or allow (liquid) to flow over the edge of its container, especially unintentionally.
> - (of liquid) flow over the edge of its container.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *spill* for anything that is fluid-like.  Liquids are obviously fluids, but mass quantities of small things can also act as fluids in certain instances.  Things in open bushels or buckets often fit this criteria, but non-actual-liquid things in closed bags often do not.

Or, put another way, if you can say *pour X*, you can say *spill X*.

You could use it for a large bucket/bushel of green beans but not really a bag of them.  Unless it's a large bag with an open top (i.e. like a bucket or bushel).  Because you don't pour greens beans from a bag typically.  (Other types of beans might work with *spill*).

Comment: I'm not really sure the size of the bag makes much of a difference. I was picturing a pretty small bag in my head, and I think the sentence is fine. If you don't spill the green beans, what do you do? Drop them, with their inertia sending them sprawling across the floor? I just don't a more suitable alternative. Also, I think it's perfectly possible to pour green beans from a bag. What if you've got a relatively small bag of prewashed green beans, and you want to put them in a casserole dish. You could pluck them out and place them in the dish one at a time, or you could just pour them out.